# Collection doesn't work in template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I send a model to a template. The model has a collection. In the template I echo some variables and functions:

```
console.log(comments);
console.log(_.size(comments));
console.log(comments instanceof App.Collections.Comments);
console.log(_.pluck(comments, 'created'));
_.each(comments, function(com) {
    console.log(com);
});
```

The first three work, but the last two underscore functions don't. Pluck gives 3x undefined and each doesn't iterate.

```
Object { length=3, models=[3], _byId={...}, more...}
3
true
[undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

How do I get the underscore functions to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone collections [have some Underscore methods mixed in](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) so you can use the Underscore methods directly on the collection instance:

```
console.log(comments.pluck('created'));
comments.each(function(com) { console.log(com) });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/3jRNX/

This one:

```
console.log(_.size(comments));
```

works fine for you because `_.size` looks like this:

```
_.size = function(obj) {
  return _.toArray(obj).length;
};
```

and `_.toArray` calls the collection's `toArray`:

```
// Safely convert anything iterable into a real, live array.
_.toArray = function(iterable) {
  if (!iterable)                return [];
  if (iterable.toArray)         return iterable.toArray();
  if (_.isArray(iterable))      return slice.call(iterable);
  if (_.isArguments(iterable))  return slice.call(iterable);
  return _.values(iterable);
};
```

which unwraps the collection's data to give you the correct length. The above is taken from the 1.3.1 source, the [current Github master version](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L310)'s `_.size` has a different implementation so your `_.size` call is likely to break during an upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to call pluck directly on the collection, as the Collection class supports it:

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-pluck

So instead of:

```
_.pluck(comments, 'created')
```

You chould call:

```
comments.pluck('created');
```

Comment: No problem, glad we could help!